# Escape character for sqare brackets in php swagger annotation json property

Tags: php, json, annotations, swagger-2.0, swagger-php

I write API in Php Laravel and use swagger (2.0) annotations (lib: [darkaonline/l5-swagger](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger) which use [swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php))  to generate swagger.json, however I have following problem - when I type:

```
/**
 *
 * Space Schema
 *
 * @SWG\Get(
 *     path="/api/v1/client/space/schema",
 *     @SWG\Response( 
 *        response=200, 
 *        description="OK",
 *        @SWG\Property(property="result", type="json", example={ "aa": [ "bb", "cc" ] }  )
 *      )
 * )
```

And try to gen swagger.json I get:

```
[Syntax Error] Expected PlainValue, got '[' in ...
```

But when I not use square brackets like for example:

```
@SWG\Property(property="result", type="json", example={ "ee": "ff" })
```

Then everything is fine. However I need to use square brackets so the question is:

**What is escape character for `[` (square bracket) in json string in swagger annotations?**

I also wanna add that my example json is quite big and complicated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I accidentally found better solution:

Change square brackets (`[` and `]`) in:

```
@SWG\Property(property="result", type="json", example={ "aa": [ "bb", "cc" ] }  )
```

to braces (`{` and `}`):

```
@SWG\Property(property="result", type="json", example={ "aa": { "bb", "cc" } }  )
```

As you can see, we use braces, however we not use key:value conwention (only keys) so swagger is able to detect array.

[image]

And we have nice and easy formatted json in swagger-ui :)

Answer (score 1):

I found some workaround which is not 100% satisfying however I will put it here:

Change

```
@SWG\Property(property="result", type="json", example={ "aa": [ "bb", "cc" ] }  )
```

to:

```
@SWG\Property(property="result", type="json", example="{ ""aa"": [ ""bb"", ""cc"" ] }" )
```

You can use [this regexp](https://regex101.com/r/r08XOy/1) to convert quotes in your json.

If you have some problem you can also change `type="json"` to

`type="string", format="json"`

hovewer be very carrefull with that because you change API result definition...

The drawback of this solution is that in [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) You will not get nice formatted json but string with doubled `""` however if you click on "Model" then you duplication will dissapear and developer will be able to copy example json

[image]